# Accessing terms statistics in Lucene 4

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval, language-model

I have a Lucene index, and I need to access some statistics such as term collection frequency. `BasicStats` class has this information, however, I could not understand whether this class is accessible.

Is it possible to access `BasicStats` class in Lucene 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BasicStats` on it's own won't do much for you.  About all it does is hold values for you, it doesn't have any of the intelligence to *acquire* that information.

`BasicStats` is intended to be used by the `Similarity` implementation, which generates all the information to put into it.  The methods it uses to do this in the `SimilarityBase` are protected, but we can make use of the code there.  To populate the `BasicStats`, you'll also need a `CollectionStatistics` and a `TermStatistics`, but really all you'll need to get those is the `Term` you are interested in, and an `IndexReader`:

```
public static BasicStats getBasicStats(IndexReader indexReader, Term myTerm, float queryBoost) throws IOException {
    String fieldName = myTerm.field();

    CollectionStatistics collectionStats = new CollectionStatistics(
            "field",
            indexReader.maxDoc(),
            indexReader.getDocCount(fieldName),
            indexReader.getSumTotalTermFreq(fieldName),
            indexReader.getSumDocFreq(fieldName)
            );

    TermStatistics termStats = new TermStatistics(
            myTerm.bytes(),
            indexReader.docFreq(myTerm),
            indexReader.totalTermFreq(myTerm)
            );

    BasicStats myStats = new BasicStats(fieldName, queryBoost);
    assert collectionStats.sumTotalTermFreq() == -1 || collectionStats.sumTotalTermFreq() >= termStats.totalTermFreq();
    long numberOfDocuments = collectionStats.maxDoc();

    long docFreq = termStats.docFreq();
    long totalTermFreq = termStats.totalTermFreq();

    if (totalTermFreq == -1) {
      totalTermFreq = docFreq;
    }

    final long numberOfFieldTokens;
    final float avgFieldLength;

    long sumTotalTermFreq = collectionStats.sumTotalTermFreq();

    if (sumTotalTermFreq <= 0) {
        numberOfFieldTokens = docFreq;
        avgFieldLength = 1;
    } else {
        numberOfFieldTokens = sumTotalTermFreq;
        avgFieldLength = (float)numberOfFieldTokens / numberOfDocuments;
    }

    myStats.setNumberOfDocuments(numberOfDocuments);
    myStats.setNumberOfFieldTokens(numberOfFieldTokens);
    myStats.setAvgFieldLength(avgFieldLength);
    myStats.setDocFreq(docFreq);
    myStats.setTotalTermFreq(totalTermFreq);

    return myStats;
}
```

If all you are after is one or two specific figures (that is, a call or two to `IndexReader`), this is probably overkill, but there it is.

Comment: Thanks!
What is should be the value of `queryBoost` parameter?
Assuming I am interested in the statistics of a single term.

Comment: @EladKravi - That's the boost applied to the term in the query.  Remember, the purpose of the `BasicStats` class is to track data for the Similarity impl, so it's using these statistics to calculate scores.  Hmm, should have made that a float, actually...